# Using existing data with Liquibase?

Tags: mysql, database, versioning, liquibase

When using Liquibase, is there any way to use existing data to generate some of the data that is to be inserted?

For example, say I'd want to update a row with id 5, but I don't know up front that the id will be 5, as this is linked to another table where I will actually be getting the id from. Is there any way for me to tell Liquibase to get the id from SELECT query?

I'm guessing this isn't really possible as I get the feeling Liquibase is really designed for a very structured non-dynamic approach, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible write your own [custom refactoring class](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_refactoring_class) to generate SQL. The functionality is designed to support the generation of static SQL based on the changeset's parameters.

So.. it's feasible to obtain a connection to the database, but the health warning attached to this approach is that the generated SQL is dynamic (your data could change) and tied tightly to your database instance.

An example of problems this will cause is an inability to generate a SQL upgrade script for a DBA to run against a production database.

I've been thinking about this use-case for some time. I still don't know if liquibase is the best solution for this data management problem or whether it needs to be combined with an additional tool like [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the built-in changes to insert data based on existing data, but you can use the  tag with insert statements with nested selects.

For example:

```
<changeSet>
  <sql>insert into person (name, manager_id) values ('Fred', (select id from person where name='Ted'))</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Note: the SQL (and support for insert+select) depends on database vendor.